# Socket.io emit data from post request to all sockets

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to emit data to all the connected sockets when a request is sent to one of the API routes.

This is my setup:

app.js:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);  
require('./router')(app, io);
```

router.js:

```
module.exports = function (app, io) {

    ...

    app.post('/api/example', function (req, res) {
        console.log(io.sockets);
        io.sockets.emit('example', req.body);
    });
};
```

In the above console message I see that there are connections.

Client (Reactjs):

```
compontentDidMount: function(){

  socket.on('example', function(payload){   
    console.log(payload);
  });
}
```

The payload is never printed in the client.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: You didn't have typo `componentDidMount` in your code, right?

Comment: oh my god, wow, @HankChiu you are a life saver, cant believe i missed that